# Negating a parameter: "Unable to resolve symbol: -x in this context"

Tags: clojure

```
(defn my-fun [x]
    (println -x))
```

Executing this code, i get:

```
Unable to resolve symbol: -x in this context
```

Why can't i just invert x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dashes are valid symbols in names.

To do a unary negation, you'd treat it like you would any other function:

```
(println (- x))
```

From the [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-):

> If no ys are supplied, returns the negation of x . . .